# insert data into table by extracting data from other table

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert values by extracting from another table but I got `exception`sqlsyntax error while trying this way

```
int row=st.executeUpdate("insert into bug_history (bug_h_id,type,summary,desc,ans) 
select bug_id,type,summary,desc,solution 
from bug_details 
where bug_id="+bug_id);
```

Comment: `desc` is reserved keyword in mysql.

Comment: it works when i changed desc to description Thanks @Vicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as follow. Use `Backtick` symbol

```
INSERT INTO bug_history (`bug_h_id`, `type`, `summary`, `desc`, `ans`) 
SELECT `bug_id`, `type`, `summary`, `desc`, `solution` 
FROM   bug_details 
WHERE  bug_id = bugID
```